# Popular matriz em C

Tags: c

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver, acredito ser erro bem primário.

Preciso popular uma matriz `(i,j)`, porém, quando mando imprimir a matriz, dá um `Bus error` ou `Segmentation fault`.

**Vejam o código abaixo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LINHAS 8
#define COLUNAS 10

int main(){
  double matrizA[LINHAS][COLUNAS];
  srand(time(NULL));

  for(int i = 1; i <= LINHAS; i++){
    printf("Valor de I: %d\n", i);
    for(int j = 1; j <= COLUNAS; j++){
      matrizA[i][j] = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*10.0-1.0;
      printf("(%d,%d): %lf\n", i,j,matrizA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("-----------------\n");
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: A indexação é de `0 a 7` no caso das **LINHAS** e de `0 a 9` no caso das **COLUNAS**, está aí o seu erro. Está a fazer indexação de `1 a 8` e de `1 a 10`. Entendeu ou precisa de uma resposta?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida, desculpe, posso estar errado, mas no for eu coloquei que é menor ou igual, teoricamente ele teria que percorrer as 10 posições para colunas e 8 para linhas. Certo?

Comment: O array é indexado a 0 e tem 8 **LINHAS**, ou seja tem os indexes `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`. Se tenta aceder ao index 8, que não existe, está a aceder a um pedaço de memória que não lhe pertence. Como colocou `<=` e o 8 é igual a 8 vai fazer `matrizA[8]` e isto não é permitido.

Comment: O problema é justamente ter usado o `<=`, faça as contas e verá que teoricamente e praticamente ele vai de 1 a 8 e depois de 1 a 10, se que percorrer um array deve ir de 0 a 7 e 0 a 9.

Comment: É verdade! Removi ele agora e deu certo, cabeça não tá boa. Coisa básica mesmo tô viajando. Valeu!